# dynamically modify HTTP POST data

Tags: http, squid, packet-sniffers, tcpdump

I set up a squid proxy server, and I would like to monitor and modify certain HTTP POST requests before it goes out of squid.  What are my options?

Comment: "setup tcpdump to sniff squid"?  Squid is running on a certain port, and if you tcpdump traffic from/to that port, you'll see all the Squid traffic.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the Squid page on Content Adaptation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation) to find what you're looking for.  Those are valid options, although the only really good one is new in Squid 3.

Another option, and what I use personally for this, is to transparently redirect the request to a script which modifies it and then forwards the changed version to the original destination.

Comment: Which of them is the "only really good one"? I've looked at all of them, but none seems easy to use for content adaptation. Thanks

Comment: @Claudiu It looks to me like eCAP is the way to go. When I wrote the post, I was referring to Client Streams, but they seem to have languished since then.